# Run OpenJDK applet in Internet Explorer

Tags: java, applet

I have a site which launches a Java applet running on Internet Explorer. The Java on the clients is Oracle JRE 1.8.
I would like to switch to OpenJDK.

As far as I understand, when the Oracle JRE is installed, it also installs Oracle Helper plug-ins in IE. Is there an OpenJDK equivalent plugin?

Comment: There is IcedTea-Web, but I believe it will only support java web start, not applets. And applets are essentially dead. You may wish to consider porting as soon as possible. [Some discussion here](http://openjdk.5641.n7.nabble.com/how-to-use-IcedTea-web-in-IE-Internet-explorer-on-windows-td343552.html)

Comment: Thanks Kevin. Looks like IE is not supported by IcedTea-Web :(